# ImageMagick convert: making xbm format images out of fonts

Tags: fonts, imagemagick

I'm using the command below to convert font characters into small xbm format images. For example, this line converts 'A' into 1.xmb

`convert -font Nimbus-Mono-L -pointsize 10 label:A 1.xbm`

This works fine for all characters except '\'. I can't figure out how to escape the '\' properly so that the conversion works.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

How to escape things depends on your shell. Assuming `bash`, you can do:

```
magick -pointsize 200 label:'\\' result.jpg
```

[image]

Or, *"Hideous Hacks R Us"*, use a forward slash and flip it:

```
magick -pointsize 100 label:"/" -flip result.jpg
```

[image]